# How do I get Lxml to read a browser I am currently on in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

So I have my browser open, I want it to be able to read information in inspect element that is constantly updating. I do not want it to "open" a browser or do it in the background, I need it reading what browser and tab I am on. Here is what I have that reads in the background

```
import requests
from lxml import html
page = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hN_q-_nGv4U')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
comment_count = tree.xpath('//*[@id="count"]/yt-formatted-string/span[1]')
print(comment_count)
```

But I need this to access my current browser and read data, not open a 'phantom' browser. I am open to using other libraries and I am a beginner coder (like 2 months since I started) and this project is to help younger family member. Thanks if anyone has any ideas

Comment: lxml is an XML library. You cannot use it to "access" your browser. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i used selenium instead. i am trying to access data from inspect element in a webbrowser game to get data. But apparently it is very hard to do it because the game is like a "script" and its not browser data. I can see the data I need in inspect element but I still scrape it in anyway. So I am going to just learn visual detection

Comment: In its current form, the question is not really answerable. The Python code is completely irrelevant if your actual problem is about reading data from a web browser.